# MVVM Silverlight 4 Parent Child View Models

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, viewmodel, parent

I have a page that holds a number combo boxes. Each combo box is bound to a separate viewmodel. How would I get all the values from the comboboxes and pass them to another viewmodel (using mvvm)?

I've briefly looked into creating a new viewmodel with properties that are the combobox viewmodels but the binding doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Graeme

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should have the parent bind to the SelectedItem of the combobox.  My fear is that your SelectedItem is already bound to your ComboBox's view model, but that is *generally* not a good idea.

ViewModels should be used only privately in a control.  So for example, in your combobox, you might want to instead create a new user control that contains that combobox.  This way, you can handle all of your 'child' view model stuff in the user control and the consumer of your new user control can bind and interact with any element it chooses without being constrained.

Comment: Hi. To clarify. MainPage holds usercontrolA, which contains a combobox for say orders. The usercontrolA has a datacontext of OrdersViewModel. The combo itemssource is bound to the Orders collection and the selecteditem to the individual entity that is selected. The main page holds usercontrolB, usercontrolC etc which are set up in the same way but for different collections of items. These controls are work perfectly. What I want to do is, on the main page, collect all the selected values (using mvvm) when a button is pressed and do an insert into a db.

Comment: I guess if i can just bind a text box on the main page to the selected value of one of the combo boxes this would be a step in the right direction... i want to try and avoid messaging or events and keep it simple??

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have access from MainPage (or it's view model) to the ViewModels of UserControls, if so you can read property of SelectedComboBox from those ViewModels.

Comment: Yes that is correct. It would be easy for me to do this is code but I am looking for a more elegant way ie binding using mvvm not code behind, which i can't work out how to do!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you conrrectly you have ComboBoxes filled with separated ViewModels (using `ItemsSource`), so to get values from them you should bind its `SelectedItem` properties to one ViewModel.

To show you what I mean, lets assume we have 2 ViewModels:

```
public class ItemOneViewModel
{
 public Name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemTwoViewModel
{
 public Name { get; set; }
}
```

and one common ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
 public ObservableCollection<ItemOneViewModel> ComboBox1Items { get; set; }
 public ObservableCollection<ItemTwoViewModel> ComboBox2Items { get; set; }

 public ItemOneViewModel SelectedItemFromComboBox1 { get; set; }
 public ItemTwoViewModel SelectedItemFromComboBox2 { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can bind:

- `ComboBox1Items` with `ItemsSource` of `ComboBox1`
- `SelectedItemFromComboBox1`  with `SelectedItem` of `ComboBox1`
- `ComboBox2Items` with `ItemsSource` of `ComboBox2`
- `SelectedItemFromComboBox2`  with `SelectedItem` of `ComboBox2`

thanks to it in `MainViewModel` you have access to selected values in ComboBoxes.

I hope you understand something from my explanation ;)

The code above is simplified version of course - all ViewModels should probably implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean... do my comments above add any value?